# Exercise in C#,it doesn't work

Tags: c#

this is the problem:You are given a sequence of positive integer numbers given as string of numbers separated by a space. Write a program, which calculates their sum. Example: "43 68 9 23 318" -> 461.

That's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace Exercises2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Give some numbers");
            int i = 0, j = 0;
            string n = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] numbers = n.Split(' ');
            int[] array;
            for (i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
            {
                array = new int[int.Parse(numbers[i])];
                int s = Sum(array);
                Console.Write("the sum of your numbers is: {0} ", s);
            }
        }
        static int Sum(int[] array)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                sum += array[i];
            }
            return sum;
        }



    }


}
```

I dont know why it doesn't work,is giving me that the sum is 0.
Thank you.

Comment: I vote to close this thread because this looks like solving your homework.

Comment: It has errors in so many levels.

Comment: I get the answer "42".   Douglass Adams would be proud

Comment: You can set a breakpoint in your code and use `Debug` mode to go in step by step. You should spot both mistakes pretty quickly. Also, all your logic could be replaced by `int sum = n.Split(' ').Sum(a => Convert.ToInt32(a));`. But I guess that's not the goal of your exercise.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is:

```
array = new int[int.Parse(numbers[i])];
```

You actually create array with the length is the given numbers[i]. the array values are all 0. So

```
int s = Sum(array);
```

s is always 0.

The correct code is simple:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Give some numbers");
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        string n = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] numbers = n.Split(' ');
        int s = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            s += int.Parse(numbers[i]);
        }
        Console.Write("the sum of your numbers is: {0} ", s);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah..it was pretty simple..Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should only iterate on each element of your array of strings retrieved by .Split and sum.

working example [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IcnRjd):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Give some numbers");
        string n = Console.ReadLine();
        int sum = 0;

        foreach(var i in n.Split(' ')){
            sum += int.Parse(i);
        }

        Console.Write("the sum of your numbers is: {0} ", sum);     
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you,that's pretty awesome.

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with the code where you getting the value of user given array in summation array as initialization of array.
array = new int[int.Parse(numbers[i])];
Here this is in loop array is initialized every time the value is getting. As per your input "43 68 9 23 318". Array will initialize  by 43, then 68, then by 9 and so on. When array is initialized the values are by default 0 for int.

So Please refer this solution with proper null and integer check. Hope this will help you!.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Give some numbers");
            int i = 0;
            string n = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] numbers = n.Split(' ');
            if (numbers != null && numbers.Length > 0)
            {
                int[] array = new int[numbers.Length];
                int s = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
                {
                     // Check if numbers[i] values is integer then add to array for some
                     int number;
                     bool result = Int32.TryParse(numbers[i], out number);
                     if (result)
                     {
                         array[i] = number;
                     }
                }
                s = Sum(array);
                Console.Write("The sum of your numbers is: {0} ", s);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you,really helped!